# Mysql Cluster distribute data only one node..why?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

here are following setup

```
ndb_mgm -e show

Connected to Management Server at: us-srv1.site.vrack:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=3    @192.168.0.2  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=4    @192.168.0.1  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12, Nodegroup: 0, *)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.0.1  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12)

[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=50   @192.168.0.1  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12)
```

and this command shows this

```
root@us-srv1:~# ndb_mgm -e "ALL REPORT MemoryUsage"
Connected to Management Server at: us-srv1.tagove.vrack:1186
Node 3: Data usage is 0%(5 32K pages of total 64000)
Node 3: Index usage is 0%(8 8K pages of total 65568)
Node 4: Data usage is 24%(15940 32K pages of total 64000)
Node 4: Index usage is 7%(4672 8K pages of total 65568)
```

its fresh mysql-cluster installation and after setup i've just imported database and only one node shows memory usages.

config.ini

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=us-srv1.site.vrack
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
NodeId=1
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-node-data/
DataMemory=2000M
IndexMemory=512M
[ndbd]
hostname=us-srv2.site.vrack
NodeId=3
[ndbd]
hostname=us-srv1.site.vrack
NodeId=4
[mysqld]
hostname=us-srv1.site.vrack
NodeId=50
```

Right now i am testing this on two physical machines, us-srv1 has mysql api